# AWS Console switch role transitively twice in a row

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I use the AWS Console, to switch my role from A to B on the same account (account1). Then I would like to switch from B to role C which is on another account (account2). The switch from A to B is working, but then from B to C is not.

- B trusts in `arn:aws:iam::account1.id:role/A`
- C trusts in `arn:aws:iam::account2.id:role/B`

Is this a limitation of AWS, or should it be possible to switch roles transitively?

Comment: I suspect it is using your IAM User credentials to assume the role, rather than using Role A to assume Role B. You should add permissions for A to assume C.

Comment: That was correct. I found the official answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, **it is not possible to switch roles transitively in AWS Console**

Based on this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html):

> When you switch roles in the AWS Management Console, **the console always uses your original credentials to authorize the switch**. This applies whether you sign in as an IAM user, as a SAML-federated role, or as a web-identity federated role. For example, if you switch to RoleA, it uses your original user or federated role credentials to determine if you are allowed to assume RoleA. If you then try to switch to RoleB while you are using RoleA, your original user or federated role credentials are used to authorize your attempt, not the credentials for RoleA.